# Reducing tensor of rank two into Kronecker delta

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, kronecker-delta, kronecker-symbol

I want to understand how this particular equality is true, and here we need to use the idea of contraction of tensors to achieve this theorem?

$a_{ij}$ x $a^{ij} = \delta_j^j$

Here, a is a tensor of rank two and $\delta$ is the Kronecker Delta.

Comment: It would be nice if there were more context: do you a basis for the vectors and covectors? It looks like what you have above is something of rank $4$, a type $(2,2)$ tensor and not something of rank $2$.

Comment: Hey, @RachidAtmai, I have edited the question, as this would be the correct one. Do check on this one?